# How to add a pin / marker in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I met a new contact from another city and quickly wanted to add his contact address in maps (so that I can find it quickly when I drive down there).

Even after a lot of fiddlying, I couldn't find an easy way to simply add a "Pin" to the map. I could select places / businesses by long pressing on them and starring them. But I couldn't add my own places/pins/markers on the map.

I am using Google Maps on Asus Transformer with Honeycomb 3.2, with all updates installed.

Answer (score 6):

Google Maps for Android allows storing places/locations by *starring* them, this should also work for every place on the map, not just places and businesses.

1. Long press on the point on the map you want to star
2. The Address will load, press it
3. In the upper right corner is a little gray star, select it

These stars are also synced on [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com/) if you are logged in with your account. The star will be named after the nearest address, **but it will be exactly at the point you selected.**

Comment: Thanks but I can only star existing addresses this way. I want to add a new place / pin on the map.

Comment: I am able to do so. The star will be named after the nearest address, but it will be exactly on the point you selected.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. I can star the place but can't name it like "Friend A's house". To overcome this I email myself the current location and in computer I name it properly. This is a very lame way. So, I'm also looking for a better solution.

Comment: @roxan This is not the same problem. You should ask a question like "How can I name a stared place on Google Maps" But I doubt that this is currently possible.

Comment: @Flow Upvoting you, I didn't know the star is placed exactly where I select it. But this is not very useful since after few days I won't remember why I placed a star there. I think roxan's use-case is similar to mine.

Comment: Does this still work in the latest app? This is what I see: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oszv1eold6d74lo/2013-10-03%2015.42.56.png)

Answer (score 3):

One way you can create a custom place in Google Maps is by putting a name in parentheses after the address. For example, search for "123 4th St (Bob's Place)" and you will see a place bubble on the map with the name "Bob's Place" and the specified address. Then you can star that and save it for later.